# High performance Gantt for Visual C# (winforms)?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, directx, gantt-chart

**Hi,**

I have tried some diffrent gantt solutions for example Devexpress timelineView but the performance is way to bad!

The requirement is as follows :

- Paint appointments in diffrent colors
- Split appointments in to sections with diffrent colors¨
- Draw special icons inside appointment
- Type text in appointments
- Collision detection between appointments
- Auto row heigh adjustment to fit appointments
- Possible to calculate exact length of sections and appointments
- Possible to Drag&Drop
- Appointment tooltip (large)
- Gantt background custom painting to illustrate a schema(with colors) where the appointments is placed on

Should I build one in DirectX? Or will WPF be enouth? Or maby there is a dinished product that fits this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can whole-heartedly recommend ILOG Gantt - I've done lots with it, and it was blindingly fast and extensible, including custom painting (I was adding all kinds of random stuff). Pretty sure it has everything on your list.

(I'm not affiliated with them in any way; simply: it worked really well for me)

Comment: Is it this you are talking about : http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0A91FF6C-38A2-426F-BFE8-042B36A37B15

Comment: @SnowJim yes, but that review is entirely crazy - it worked really really well for me, and I was putting under pretty heavy load.